# Nodejs out of memory with sequelize and csv-parse

Tags: node.js, csv, sequelize.js, heap-memory

It will be too specific question I guess but I am really stuck with that.

I have a large csv file (2.7 GB) which contains product information about 6 millions. I am trying to parse the data and insert it to Postresql. I am using Sequelize for ORM and `csv-parse` module for parsing the file.

When I try to run my code I am having `JavaScript heap out of memory` error. I am using streams for reading and parsing csv file so I don't understand why it uses too much memory? Is there any issue with my snippet that cause this error? Or any better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Any help will be appreciated.

```
const csvParser = require('csv-parse'); // https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse

const Product = require('../models').Product;

const options = {
    delimiter: '|',
    trim: true,
    relax: true
}

const parser = csvParser(options);

fs.createReadStream('path/to/csv', {encoding: 'utf8'})
    .pipe(parser)
    .on('data', row => {
        processPlainRow(row);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('ended');
    })
    .on('error', error => {
        console.log('error: ', error);
    })
    .on('close', error => {
        console.log('stream closed');
    })

function processPlainRow(row) {
    let productToInsert = parsedRow(row);
    Product
        .create(row)
        .then(product => {
            // do nothing at all
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function parsedRow(row) {
    return {
        name: row['name'],
        price: row['price'],
        // ... goes on
    };
}
```

Comment: How big is the CSV?

Comment: @meyer9 2.7GB and contains ~6-7 millions of products

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32389049/2537322

Comment: @meyer9 I don't think it helps my question that much.